# How can I move visual composer content to bottom of website without impacting background?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, visual-composer

I have a question regarding to wordpress and visual-composer, I'm trying to build website for festival but I've stuck in some situation.

So basically, this is how far I've got - [Website I'm working on now](http://lecampavecam.lv/sakums/)

So I need to move that black line of cities down to website footer, so it looks like this - [Example of how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/37tt2.jpg)

Also, I don't know how to remove these white gaps? so the black content is just in footer not impacting the background image?

Thanks,
Regards

Maruja

Comment: have you checked visual composer empty space element

Comment: Hi Mudassar, Yes I tried it as well, but it doesn't work with the background I have, it automatically creates a big white blank space which I don't need..

Comment: in your visual composer..... select container and give that container the background you need and in that container add the element you want to if you want to push that element at the bottom you can do that with element top margin or with empty element